# Does jetty-monitor has been removed in Jetty 9?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I need to monitor the Jetty threads and expose metrics to JMX in the runtime like the idle threads count.
My Jetty version is 9, and I found there is a document for Jetty 7/8 about jetty-monitor:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty-monitor

The feature is what I need, but it seems outdated. When I check the documentation for Jetty 9, I couldn't find the monitor-related feature.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html

Anyone know what's the new approach to monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Jetty 9 still support classes of monitoring on the library. But It isn't exist for operational section of monitoring in the document.
If you wanna get that library with Jar file, you can visit to get that on maven repository to follow below link.

[Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-monitor/9.4.0.M0)

Answer (score 1):

The features that jetty-monitor used to provide is now baked into Jetty 9.

Those values are present in JMX still.

Just make sure you have `jetty-jmx` enabled and you are good to go.